# Groupby with pandas and get the connecting rows

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am working with `pandas` and I find myself with a problem. I use `groupby` method to group my columns and find the maximum and avarage values. My problem is that I want to group by the `time_stamp` column and get the max (`values_1`) and average (`values_2`) item in values columns but I want to know that which `project_id` is the max  as well. I attached my input table and the desired table. Thank you in advance for your help!

**My input table:**

```
id          time_stamp     project_id value_1 value_2
- ---------------------------------------------------
0    2018-05-02 04:00:25          41   3       3
1    2018-05-02 04:00:25          42   4       3
2    2018-05-02 04:00:25          76   6       1
3    2018-05-02 04:00:25          39   8       7
4    2018-05-02 04:00:25          10   1       2
5    2018-05-02 04:10:25          33   3       7
6    2018-05-02 04:10:25          15   6       8
7    2018-05-02 04:10:25          34   6       9
8    2018-05-02 04:10:25          22   9       4
9    2018-05-02 04:10:25          58   6       1
```

**My desired output:**

```
id      time_stamp            max_id  value_1   value_2
- ---------------------------------------------------
3    2018-05-02 04:00:25          39   8       7
8    2018-05-02 04:10:25          22   9       4
```

**My attempt:**

```
pd_table.groupby('time_stamp').agg({'value_1':'max','value_2':'mean'}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices by max value of `value_1` column, so first create index by column `project_id` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = (pd_table.set_index('project_id')
              .groupby('time_stamp')
              .agg({'value_1':['max', 'idxmax'],'value_2':'mean'}))
print (df)
                    value_1        value_2
                        max idxmax    mean
time_stamp                                
2018-05-02 04:00:25       8     39     3.2
2018-05-02 04:10:25       9     22     5.8
```

Get `MultiIndex` in columns, so some cleaning necessary:

```
#flattening MultiIndex
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
d = {'value_1_idxmax':'max_id','value_1_max':'value_1','value_2_mean':'value_2'}
#rename and change order of columns 
df = df.rename(columns=d).reindex(columns=['max_id','value_1','value_2']).reset_index()
print (df)
            time_stamp  max_id  value_1  value_2
0  2018-05-02 04:00:25      39        8      3.2
1  2018-05-02 04:10:25      22        9      5.8
```

Comment: Great answer! Helped me a lot!

Comment: @istvan.hajdu - Nice question also :) You are welcome!